# Firebase Rules -- Multiple Default Values

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have a parent as 'Client' in my firebase. This is then followed by a child of 'invoices' and then followed by children on the invoice

```
'clients' {
    'uid' {
       'invoices' {
          'number': '1003 //etc...
          'payments' {

           }
           'history' {

           }
           'discussion' {

           }
       }
    }
 }
```

I am trying to only allow clients to write to payments, history, and discussion. But when I do the following I get an error `Cannot have multiple default rules ('$payments' and '$history').` in the Firebase Dashboard Rules Section.

```
"clients": {
      ".write" : "root.child('roles').child(auth.uid).child('level').val() == 4",
      ".indexOn" : "number",
      "$estimates": {
        "$discussion": {
          ".write": "root.child('roles').child(auth.uid).child('level').val() == 2"
        }
      },
      "$invoices": {
        "$payments": {
          ".write": "root.child('roles').child(auth.uid).child('level').val() == 2"
        },
        "$history": {
          ".write": "root.child('roles').child(auth.uid).child('level').val() == 2" 
        },
        "$discussion": {
          ".write": "root.child('roles').child(auth.uid).child('level').val() == 2"
        }
      }
    },
```

What is the correct way to write these rules then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing some levels from your JSON tree in the rules.

```
"clients": {
   "$clientid": {
      ".write" : "root.child('roles').child(auth.uid).child('level').val() == 4",
      "invoices": {
         ".indexOn" : "number",
         "$invoiceid": {
            "payments": {
               ".write": "root.child('roles').child(auth.uid).child('level').val() == 2"
            },
            "history": {
               ".write": "root.child('roles').child(auth.uid).child('level').val() == 2" 
            },
            "discussion": {
               ".write": "root.child('roles').child(auth.uid).child('level').val() == 2"
            }
         }
      },
```

You should only use $ variables for a rule that needs to be applied to all non-otherwise matched children under a node.

So if you keep all payments as children of the `payments` node and want specific validation rules for them, you could:

```
            "payments": {
               ".write": "root.child('roles').child(auth.uid).child('level').val() == 2",
               "$paymentid": {
                  ".validate": "..."
               }
            },
```